# How can I scale the .tikz picture? I tried using tikzpicture but then it says TeX Capacity exceeded, so I sticked to minipage

Tags: tikz-pgf, minipage, scale, capacity

```
\begin{figure}[H]
    \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \def\svgwidth{1.0\textwidth}
    \def\svgwidth{100pt}
    \import{pdf/}{/diodebridge.tikz}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \def\svgwidth{1.0\textwidth}
    \import{pdf/}{diode.pdf_tex}
    \end{minipage}
\caption{1 & 2}
\label{fig:diode}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: we can not run your example to see any issues but if you want them side by side use `\end{minipage}%` with a `%` as you can not have a  space between two  `.5\linewidth` minipage as they would then not fit

Comment: I tried using % after \end{minipage} but it still doesnt work. Should I change the .5\linewidth? I have a picture uploaded here [link](https://imgur.com/a/iMSUREE). As you can see the plotted curves extend an usual A4 page.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can add images that show the problem to your question directly. Use the "Edit" link to add more information. It is, however, impossible for us to help you since 1) we don't have access to the two files you include into your main file and 2) you did not provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: Hello Mister Habicht? Can I add the two data for you so you can see the problem? 
It would happen in every case, if you include the .tikz file.